# Citing a Reprint of an Article in BibTeX

Tags: bibtex, natbib, texshop

How do I cite a reprint of a given article? I want to cite the postscript of Lewis's Counterpart Theory & QML which only appears in his Philosophical Paper vol. 1. I have the info in my bibtex entry, but how do I get it to show up in my bibliography?

Here is the entry:

```
@article{LewisCTQML,
Author = {David Lewis},
Date-Modified = {2007-03-24 18:24:14 -0400},
Journal = {Journal of Philosophy},
Pages = {113--26},
Reprintedin = {LewisPP1},
Reprintpages = {26--46},
Title = {Counterpart Theory and Quantified Modal Logic},
Volume = {65},
Year = {1968}}
```

But when I call it via `\citep{LewisCTQML}` it drops the reprint info from my references and only displays Author, Journal, Pages, Title, Volume, and Year.

Is this something that is an easy fix? Do I just need to create a new entry for the reprint?

Running `TeXShop` on Mac OS X 10.7.4, `BibTeX` with `natbib`, `BibDesk` to manage my `.bib`, and the `phil_review.bst` from http://tedsider.org/latex/phil_review.bst

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A fast solution could be to add

```
note={reprinted in LewisPP1, pages 26--46}
```

in your article entry. With a little pretty printing you get:

```
@article{LewisCTQML,
  Author        = {David Lewis},
  Date-Modified = {2007-03-24 18:24:14 -0400},
  Journal       = {Journal of Philosophy},
  Pages         = {113--26},
  Reprintedin   = {LewisPP1},
  Reprintpages  = {26--46},
  Title         = {Counterpart Theory and Quantified Modal Logic},
  Volume        = {65},
  Year          = {1968},
  note          = {reprinted in LewisPP1, pages 26--46}, 
}
```