# Cite video using BibTeX in BibDesk

Tags: bibtex

I am having trouble citing a video in BibDesk.  It doesn't have a field for Producer.

The desired output format is apa6.

example APA format:

American Psychological Association. (Producer). (2000). Responding therapeutically to patient expressions of sexual attraction [DVD]. Available from http://www.apa.org/videos/

I'm writing a paper in LaTeX and using apacite.  How would I create that entry?

Thanks,

Dan

---

```
@misc{ex65-3,
  author    = {{\bibcorporate{American Psychological Association (Producer)}}},
  firstkey  = {{American Psychological Association [APA]}},
  key       = {{APA}},
  year      = {2000},
  title     = {Responding Therapeutically to Patient Expressions of
           Sexual Attraction: A Stimulus Training Tape},
  type      = {Motion picture},
  note      = {Available from the American Psychological Association,
           750 First Street, NE, Washington, DC 20002-4242},
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add fields to a `BibDesk` entry by right-clicking by the fields in the pop-up window for the entry. It is the first option, "Add Field".

The only question is whether your `bst` supports a "Producer" field. I recently had a similar problem trying to cite a reprint of an article. I had added a "Reprintedin" field to the `BibDesk` entry only to find out that my `bst` didn't support that field.

You can see my question and the answer here: [Citing a Reprint of an Article in BibTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68139/citing-a-reprint-of-an-article-in-bibtex)

I was able to solve the problem with a "note" field (which was supported by my `bst`).

Looking at the `apacite` documentation (here: http://wiki.humlab.lu.se/dokuwiki/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=public:apacite.pdf) it doesn't seem like there is a "Producer" field available (see page 15 for a table of the fields and which types of entries support which fields).

I would suggest that as a quick fix you simply put the producer's name into whichever field appears second in the references in the type of entry you are using.

Comment: I was able to add it before the title with brackets around it, but it is making it italicized.  How would I make it regular not italic text?  Thanks.

Comment: This is getting a bit out of my area of knowledge (I'm only a beginning LaTeX user myself).

I supspect that what is doing the italicization is your .bst, so the "real" fix would be to modify your .bst. But that is over my head (and if you could do that you could add a field for "Producer" defined as you like).

Now, I know that if you use the `amsmath` package then if you use math mode you can de-italicize something by entering the command `\text`. So, you might try something like:

    `$\text{Producer}$`

In the entry field, but frankly I don't know if that will work, it's just a guess.

Comment: I just checked my suggestion with one of my own documents and it didn't work, so I suspect it will be a no-go for you too. Sorry I can't be of more help!

Comment: Thanks Dennis.  So are we stuck?  Latex with apacite doesn't support video citations?  This would seem to be a pretty big limitation if I am writing a paper and I need to cite something I am using from a video.  I'll work on it when I get a chance.  I ended up turning in a paper with the incorrect format.

Comment: There's definitely a way to do it, I'm just a LaTeX novice so aside from these sort of ugly solutions I'm not too good at fixing these sorts of things. If my ugly solution doesn't work, I ask a question here.

Comment: Thanks Dennis for your help.  I'm just starting out too, so these little problems actually help to learn it.  I went through the documentation carefully and found an example that had producer in it using the \bibcorporate command in the author field.