# Workaround for reprinted items in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, biber, apa-style

I am trying to find a way to indicate that a chapter is a reprint (in the following MWE, `test1` is a reprint of `test2`). I had a look at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68139/citing-a-reprint-of-an-article-in-bibtex) but I would like a solution that does not require adding fields such as `Reprintedin` and `Reprintpages` to the `.bib` file, since my `.bib` is produced by Zotero and the type of fields are given (although I could add a `note` field).

Is there a way to cross cite (or any other workaround)?

Please consider the following MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
@incollection{test1,
    address = {London},
    title = {Deliberation and democratic legitimacy},
    isbn = {0415302102},
    lccn = {JA71 .D36 2003},
    booktitle = {Debates in contemporary political philosophy: {An} anthology},
    publisher = {Routledge},
    author = {Cohen, Joshua},
    editor = {Matravers, Derek and Pike, Jonathan E.},
    year = {2003 [1989]},
    pages = {342--360},
}
@book{test2,
    address = {Oxford},
    title = {The {Good} polity: {Normative} analysis of the state},
    isbn = {0631158049},
    lccn = {JC325 .G59 1989},
    shorttitle = {The {Good} polity},
    publisher = {Blackwell},
    editor = {Hamlin, Alan P. and Pettit, Philip},
    year = {1989}
}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}


% Set the values for the bibliography
\usepackage[
    style=apa,
    backend=biber,
    isbn=false,
    url=false,
    doi=false,
    eprint=false,
    hyperref=true,
    backref=false,
    firstinits=false,
]{biblatex}

% Recommended by biblatex
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}

% Set language
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}

\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{test1}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Ideally, what I would like to obtain is the following in-text citation:

> (Cohen, 2003 [1989])

and the following full citation in the Reference list:

> Cohen, J. (2003). Deliberation and democratic legitimacy. In D.
>   Matravers & J. E. Pike (Eds.), Debates in contemporary political
>   philosophy: An anthology (pp. 342–360). (Reprinted from *The Good
>   polity: Normative analysis of the state*, pp. 17-34, by A. P. Hamlin &
>   P. Pettit, Eds., 1989, Oxford: Blackwell). London: Routledge.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no need to alter the `bib` file. It is possible to add the information about the original publication using `\DeclareSourcemap`

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=entrykey, match=\regexp{test1},
            fieldset=related, fieldvalue={test2}]
      \step[fieldsource=entrykey, match=\regexp{test1},
            fieldset=relatedtype, fieldvalue={reprintfrom}]
    }
  }
}
```

The `apa` biblatex style does not include the date of the reprint in the bibliographic info. Thus we can patch it using the `xpatch` package (i.e., use `\usepackage{xpatch}` to load it) and the following code

```
\xpatchbibmacro{related:reprintfrom}
  {\usebibmacro{location+publisher}}
  {\usebibmacro{date}\setunit{\addcomma\addspace}\usebibmacro{location+publisher}}
  {}
  {}
```

Similarly `apa` does not specify the that the editors of a work from  which the reprint originates are editors. Thus we can add the string `ed/eds` by patching again the `bibmacro` used for related work of type `reprintfrom` (`related:reprintfrom`)

```
\xpatchbibmacro{related:reprintfrom}
  {\printnames[apanames][-\value{listtotal}]{editor}}
  {\printnames[apanames][-\value{listtotal}]{editor}%
    \ifnameundef{editor}{}{\addcomma\addspace\usebibmacro{apaeditorstrg}{editor}}}
  {}
  {}
```

Finally to print the full text `Reprint from` there are two alternatives: the first is to load the option `abbreviate=false` of `biblatex` (but it has the effect to turn off all the abbreviations) or we can redefine the bibliography string associated to it (`reprintfrom`); this can be done as in the following code:

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{british}{
  reprintfrom = {Reprinted from}
}
```

Comment: Changed collaborator to editor in the post's MWE. Thanks.

Comment: Very last thing. How to display the number of pages `...Normative analysis of the state, pp. 17-34, by A. P. Hamlin...`? They are not in the bib entry of the original work, so may be should I try to define it in the first `\DeclareSourcemap`?

Comment: Also (advanced feature) would it be possible to populate the field `pages` in the referred original work (`test2`) programmatically by searching in field `note` of `test1` for a match with `pp. dd-dd`?