# How to differentiate between translated and reprinted work with APA style

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies, citing, apa-style

This question is an upgrade to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/138891/workaround-for-reprinted-items-in-bibliography) (already answered) question.

I am using `biblatex-apa` with `biber` as backend.

According to the APA style a "translated" work should be treated differently from a "reprinted" work. A "[translated](http://www.cws.illinois.edu/workshop/writers/citation/apa/translated/)" work will simply indicate the translator and at the end the original date of publication (`...Somepress. (Original work published 1923)`), without indicating any other additional information about the source work on which the translation is based. Similarly to a "republished" or "[reprinted book](http://www.cws.illinois.edu/workshop/writers/citation/apa/reprintedbook/)". On the contrary a "[reprinted chapter](http://www.cws.illinois.edu/workshop/writers/citation/apa/reprintedchapters/)" will need to indicate the original title of the book, pages the chapter/article was originally published at, author/editor of the original book, year of original publication, city and publisher.

I have then added two fields to my bibliography to store information on reference to original work `reprintedfrom` (in case the chapter/article was already printed) and original publication pages `origpages`.

I am then looking for a macro that will tell the difference between a translated, republished or reprinted book and a republished chapter/article.

In the first case should print

> Buber, M. (1937). *I and thou* (R. G. Smith, Trans.). Edinburgh: T. & T.
>   Clark. (Original work published 1923)

with in-text parenthetical citations: `(Buber, 1923/1937)`;

while in the second

> Cohen, J. (1997). Deliberation and democratic legitimacy. In J. Bohman
>   & W. Rehg (Eds.), *Deliberative democracy: Essays on reason and
>   politics* (pp. 67–91). Cambridge, MA: MIT Press. (Reprinted from *The
>   Good polity: Normative analysis of the state*, pp. 17-34, by A. P.
>   Hamlin & P. Pettit, Eds., 1989, Oxford: Blackwell)

with in-text parenthetical citations: `(Cohen, 1989/1997)`.

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/138891/workaround-for-reprinted-items-in-bibliography/138894#138894) offers a macro to add fields to the bibliography for specific bib items and add them at the end of reference:

> Cohen, J. (1997). Deliberation and democratic legitimacy. In J. Bohman
>   & W. Rehg (Eds.), *Deliberative democracy: Essays on reason and
>   politics* (pp. 67–91). Cambridge, MA: MIT Press. (Reprinted from *The
>   Good polity: Normative analysis of the state*, by A. P.
>   Hamlin & P. Pettit, Eds., 1989, Oxford: Blackwell) (Original work published 1989)

Problem is it won't add the number of pages for the original work and won't remove `(Original work published 1989)` that now is redundant in the complete citation.

I am interested to know if it is possible to tweak [these macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/138891/workaround-for-reprinted-items-in-bibliography/138894#138894) to obtain the different citation styles as described above.

Please consider the following

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
@book{test1,
    address = {Edinburgh},
    title = {I and thou},
    publisher = {T. \& {T}. {Clark}},
    author = {Buber, Martin},
    translator = {Smith, Ronald Gregor},
    year = {1937},
    origdate = {1923}
}
@incollection{test2,
    address = {Cambridge, {MA}},
    title = {Deliberation and democratic legitimacy},
    booktitle = {Deliberative democracy: {Essays} on reason and politics},
    publisher = {MIT {Press}},
    author = {Cohen, Joshua},
    editor = {Bohman, James and Rehg, William},
    year = {1997},
    origdate = {1989},
    reprintedfrom = {test3},
    origpages = {17--34},
    pages = {67--91}
}
@book{test3,
    address = {Oxford},
    title = {The {Good} polity: {Normative} analysis of the state},
    shorttitle = {The {Good} polity},
    publisher = {Blackwell},
    editor = {Hamlin, Alan P. and Pettit, Philip},
    year = {1989}
}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}


% Set the values for the bibliography
\usepackage[
    style=apa,
    backend=biber,
    isbn=false,
    url=false,
    doi=false,
    eprint=false,
    hyperref=true,
    backref=false,
    firstinits=false,
]{biblatex}

% Recommended by biblatex
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}

% Set language
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}

\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{test1} 

\cite{test2}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This is the output

[image]

while I am trying to get

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to try this slightly modified mapping command

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=reprintedfrom, fieldtarget=related, final]
      \step[fieldset=relatedtype, fieldvalue={reprintfrom}]
    }
  }
}
```

It will turn the non-standard `reprintedfrom={something}` into `related={something}` and `relatedtype={reprintfrom}`.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{test1,
    address = {Edinburgh},
    title = {I and thou},
    publisher = {T. \& {T}. {Clark}},
    author = {Buber, Martin},
    translator = {Smith, Ronald Gregor},
    year = {1937},
    origdate = {1923}
}
@incollection{test2,
    address = {Cambridge, {MA}},
    title = {Deliberation and democratic legitimacy},
    booktitle = {Deliberative democracy: {Essays} on reason and politics},
    publisher = {MIT {Press}},
    author = {Cohen, Joshua},
    editor = {Bohman, James and Rehg, William},
    year = {1997},
    origdate = {1989},
    reprintedfrom = {test3},
    pages = {67--91},
}
@book{test3,
    address = {Oxford},
    title = {The {Good} polity: {Normative} analysis of the state},
    shorttitle = {The {Good} polity},
    publisher = {Blackwell},
    editor = {Hamlin, Alan P. and Pettit, Philip},
    year = {1989},
    pages = {17--34},% that's better than origpages in test2
}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}


% Set the values for the bibliography
\usepackage[
    style=apa,
    backend=biber,
    isbn=false,
    url=false,
    doi=false,
    eprint=false,
    hyperref=true,
    backref=false,
    firstinits=false,
]{biblatex}

% Recommended by biblatex
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}

% Set language
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{related:reprintfrom}[1]{%
  \entrydata*{#1}{%
    \printtext{\mkbibemph{\printfield[apacase]{title}}}%
    \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
    \printfield{pages}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
    \bibstring{byauthor}\addspace
    \printnames[apanames][-\value{listtotal}]{editor}%
    \ifnameundef{editor}
      {}
      {\addcomma\addspace
       \usebibmacro{apaeditorstrg}{editor}}
    \printnames[apanames][-\value{listtotal}]{author}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
    \usebibmacro{date}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
    \usebibmacro{location+publisher}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{related}}}


\DefineBibliographyStrings{british}{
  reprintfrom = {Reprinted from}
}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=reprintedfrom, fieldtarget=related, final]
      \step[fieldset=relatedtype, fieldvalue={reprintfrom}]
    }
  }
}

\renewbibmacro*{origyear}{%
  \ifboolexpr{not test {\iffieldundef{labelyear}} and not test {\iffieldsequal{labelyear}{origyear}} and not test {\iffieldequalstr{relatedtype}{reprintfrom}}}
    {\printfield{origyear}}
    {}}

\begin{document}
  \cite{test1}
  \cite{test2}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

A problem though is `origpages`; the best solution is to add the contents of `origpages` as `pages` to the related entry as done above.

---

But if you cannot, for the life of you, live with changing your bibsource, this redefinition of `related:reprintfrom` might be for you.

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{origpages}{\mkpageprefix[bookpagination]{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{related:reprintfrom}[1]{%
  \entrydata*{#1}{%
    \printtext{\mkbibemph{\printfield[apacase]{title}}}}%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{origpages}%
  \entrydata*{#1}{%
    \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
    \bibstring{byauthor}\addspace
    \printnames[apanames][-\value{listtotal}]{editor}%
    \ifnameundef{editor}
      {}
      {\addcomma\addspace
       \usebibmacro{apaeditorstrg}{editor}}
    \printnames[apanames][-\value{listtotal}]{author}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
    \usebibmacro{date}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
    \usebibmacro{location+publisher}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{related}}}
```

You will have to tell `biblatex`/Biber to recognise `origpages` though. This can be done via

```
\begin{filecontents*}{biblatex-dm.cfg}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=range]{origpages}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{origpages}
\end{filecontents*}
```

Another MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{biblatex-dm.cfg}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=range]{origpages}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{origpages}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{test1,
    address = {Edinburgh},
    title = {I and thou},
    publisher = {T. \& {T}. {Clark}},
    author = {Buber, Martin},
    translator = {Smith, Ronald Gregor},
    year = {1937},
    origdate = {1923}
}
@incollection{test2,
    address = {Cambridge, {MA}},
    title = {Deliberation and democratic legitimacy},
    booktitle = {Deliberative democracy: {Essays} on reason and politics},
    publisher = {MIT {Press}},
    author = {Cohen, Joshua},
    editor = {Bohman, James and Rehg, William},
    year = {1997},
    origdate = {1989},
    reprintedfrom = {test3},
    %related = {test3},
    %relatedtype={reprintfrom},
    origpages = {17--34},
    pages = {67--91}
}
@book{test3,
    address = {Oxford},
    title = {The {Good} polity: {Normative} analysis of the state},
    shorttitle = {The {Good} polity},
    publisher = {Blackwell},
    editor = {Hamlin, Alan P. and Pettit, Philip},
    year = {1989}
}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}


% Set the values for the bibliography
\usepackage[
    style=apa,
    backend=biber,
    isbn=false,
    url=false,
    doi=false,
    eprint=false,
    hyperref=true,
    backref=false,
    firstinits=false,
]{biblatex}

% Recommended by biblatex
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}

% Set language
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{origpages}{\mkpageprefix[bookpagination]{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{related:reprintfrom}[1]{%
  \entrydata*{#1}{%
    \printtext{\mkbibemph{\printfield[apacase]{title}}}}%
    \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
    \printfield{origpages}%
  \entrydata*{#1}{%
    \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
    \bibstring{byauthor}\addspace
    \printnames[apanames][-\value{listtotal}]{editor}%
    \ifnameundef{editor}
      {}
      {\addcomma\addspace
       \usebibmacro{apaeditorstrg}{editor}}
    \printnames[apanames][-\value{listtotal}]{author}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
    \usebibmacro{date}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
    \usebibmacro{location+publisher}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{related}}}


\DefineBibliographyStrings{british}{
  reprintfrom = {Reprinted from}
}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=reprintedfrom, fieldtarget=related, final]
      \step[fieldset=relatedtype, fieldvalue={reprintfrom}]
    }
  }
}

\renewbibmacro*{origyear}{%
  \ifboolexpr{not test {\iffieldundef{labelyear}} and not test {\iffieldsequal{labelyear}{origyear}} and not test {\iffieldequalstr{relatedtype}{reprintfrom}}}
    {\printfield{origyear}}
    {}}

\begin{document}
  \cite{test1} 
  \cite{test2}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

To get rid of the `origyear` information at the end of a reprint, we modify the macro to include a test for reprinted entries (it checks if `relatedtype` is set to `reprintfrom`; the mapping takes care of that); the information is skipped if it is a reprint.

```
\renewbibmacro*{origyear}{%
  \ifboolexpr{not test {\iffieldundef{labelyear}} and not test {\iffieldsequal{labelyear}{origyear}} and not test {\iffieldequalstr{relatedtype}{reprintfrom}}}
    {\printfield{origyear}}
    {}}
```

Both MWEs yield

[image]

Comment: @Francesco Oh, sorry I missed that. Have a look at the edited answer.

Comment: Great! Then after your suggestions and to make the .bib more consistent (and to avoid too many tweaks for the page numbers) I would add the referred work as `@incollection` adding the title of the chapter/article as `title`, and also the `author` and `pages` field. The book title then becomes `booktitle`. Only thing to change then in your macro is `\printtext{\mkbibemph{\printfield[apacase]{title}}}%` to `\printtext{\mkbibemph{\printfield[apacase]{booktitle}}}%`.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting the two years to display with `\textcite`.  What part of your answer prints both years using `\cite`, and how might that be extended to other cite commands?

Comment: I'm still not sure how your example here does it, but I was able to modify the edit of [another of your answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134645/90570) to get it to do what I wanted.

Comment: @JonathanW. In `biblatex-apa` that happens automatically already (as you can see in the MWE from the question), so my answer doesn't do anything to facilitate that. But I guess you found your answer ...

Comment: Yeah, I'd come to the conclusion it might have something to do with the style.  I guess `chicago` style does something similar.  Thanks!