# Cite a Reprint with biblatex and IEEE citation Style

Tags: biblatex, biber, ieee-style

I want to cite a reprint of a paper with `biblatex` / `biber` and the `IEEE` citation style. The [fast solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68139/) to use the `note` field results in the added text "in between the reference" and not at the end as I want it for the `IEEE` style.

What I want to achieve

J. Doe, “A very important paper,” in *Conference on Important Publications*, 2000, pp. 1–42. Reprinted in J. Miller, "Collection of Important Papers," in *Book Title*, 2012, pp. 100-142.

Hence, I am looking for an easy way to add the reprint information, as the `note` field approach yields

J. Doe, “A very important paper,” in *Conference on Important Publications*, Reprinted in Miller: Collection of Important Papers, Book Title, 2019, pp. 100-142, 2000, pp. 1–42.

Please have a look at the following minimal not working example

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
@InProceedings{Author2000,
  author     = {Jon Doe},
  title      = {A Very Important Paper},
  booktitle  = {Conference on Important Publications},
  year       = {2000},
  pages      = {1--42},
  note       = {Reprinted in Miller: Collection of Important Papers, Book Title, 2019, pp. 100-142},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=ieee,
    dateabbrev=false,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{Author2000}
\printbibliography%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way to do this is to use a `related` entry.

Create your `inbook` entry as normal in your bib file.

Then add a `related` field referring to your `inbook` entry and a `relatedstring` with the the string you want to introduce the related entry with. Some are defined as localisation string, but "Reprinted in" isn't, so you'll have to specify it in full.

You'll also want to redefine `\begrelateddelim` to put a period between the main entry and the related entry in your bibliography.

## MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@InProceedings{Author2000,
  author        = {Jon Doe},
  title         = {A Very Important Paper},
  booktitle     = {Conference on Important Publications},
  date          = {2000},
  pages         = {1--42},
  related       = {Author2012},
  relatedstring = {Reprinted in}
}
@InBook{Author2012,
  author    = {J. Miller},
  title     = {Collection of Important Papers},
  booktitle = {Book Title},
  date      = {2012},
  pages     = {100-142}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=ieee,dateabbrev=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\renewcommand*{\begrelateddelim}{\addperiod\space}
\begin{document}
\cite{Author2000}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I searched for. With my biblatex version v3.10 I do not have the option `\begrelateddelim`, hence I ignored that part. What is indeed very strange is, that if I add a second source with a reprint, only the first gets the reprint information listed, in the second it is ignored. Do you know a reason for that?

Comment: @Roos Can you ask a new question with an example about the ignored `related` entry, please? Intuitively, I'd have said this should not be happening, but it is hard to tell what exactly goes wrong without seeing an example.

Comment: @moewe: I accepted the answer as it was the solution to my problem / question. For the ignored second reprint entry I opened a new question as you wished: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/489724/