# Second Reprint is ignored for biblatex and IEEE citation Style

Tags: biblatex, biber, ieee-style

I want to cite a reprint of a publication with `biblatex` and the `ieee` citation style. The [proposed solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/489568/) in my previous question worked as expected, unless I add a second publication with a reprint. In this case only the first cited paper with the reprint is correct.

Order is

```
\cite{Author2000}
\cite{Author1990}
```

[image: Reference Doe first]

With the inverse order

```
\cite{Author1990}
\cite{Author2000}
```

[image: Reference Mustermann first]

I only added two more references in [the example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/489568/) and the second `cite` command.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@InProceedings{Author1990,
  author        = {Max Mustermann},
  title         = {The original Articel},
  booktitle     = {Conference on Originality},
  date          = {1990},
  pages         = {1--4},
  related       = {Author1991},
  relatedstring = {Reprinted in}
}
@InBook{Author1991,
  author    = {Eric Meier},
  title     = {Collection of Originality},
  booktitle = {A simple Book},
  date      = {1991},
  pages     = {100-104}
}
@InProceedings{Author2000,
  author        = {Jon Doe},
  title         = {A Very Important Paper},
  booktitle     = {Conference on Important Publications},
  date          = {2000},
  pages         = {1--42},
  related       = {Author2012},
  relatedstring = {Reprinted in}
}
@InBook{Author2012,
  author    = {J. Miller},
  title     = {Collection of Important Papers},
  booktitle = {Book Title},
  date      = {2012},
  pages     = {100-142}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=ieee,dateabbrev=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
% \renewcommand*{\begrelateddelim}{\addperiod\space} % only biblatex >3.10
\begin{document}
\cite{Author1990}
\cite{Author2000}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The new version 1.3a 2019-06-19 of `biblatex-ieee` released a few days ago fixes the issues discussed in this answer. If possible, simply update `biblatex-ieee`.
>
> If the MWE from the question is run with the current version of `biblatex-ieee` the output is as expected.
>
> The answer below is kept for historical interest.

The bibliography drivers of the current release version of `biblatex-ieee` all end with the code block

```
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{related}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
```

to deal with `related` entries. This causes issues if there are several `related` entries in the bibliography, because the block is missing an initialisation macro. Instead the block should be looking more like

```
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
```

As luck would have it https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-ieee/commit/549994d193a5f6a95f96bb006840f42a5c98365d implements the required change already. Unfortunately, the change is currently only available on GitHub and has not made it to CTAN yet.

In the meantime the easiest work-around is probably to download `ieee.bbx` from https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-ieee and drop it next to your `.tex` document. Just remember to remove the local copy when the package is finally updated.

Comment: Thank you very much for figuring out the issue and pointing to the correct file. This helps a lot.